# playground settings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

when I run this small code, I don't see the result. All I see is: (11 times)

```
var name = "Karthik"

for x in 0...10 {
    print(name)
}
```

How can I display the result individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially it looks like this
[image: Initially it looks like this]

Select the quick look icon
[image: Select the quick look icon]

It opens a pop up, you'll see one value, right click it on it and select value history
[image: It opens a pop up, you'll see one value, right click it on it and select value history]

YOu'll see the list of values and can scroll through it
[image: YOu'll see the list of values and can scroll through it]

**OR**

Try to use the other option with an eye like icon called show result. Click on it
[image: Try to use the other option with an eye like icon called show result. Click on it]

You'll see that the result popped itself on the playground editor.
[image: You'll see that the result popped itself on the playground editor.]

Right click on the pop up which is now sitting in the playground editor and select value history
[image: Right click on the pop up which is now sitting in the playground editor and select value history]

YOu'll see the list of values and can scroll through it
[image: YOu'll see the list of values and can scroll through it]

HOPE THIS HELPS :)